# "python -i" equivalent in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I read this question but this doesn't answer it. [Is there a ruby equivalent of "python -i"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437582/is-there-a-ruby-equivalent-of-python-i)

If my script is,

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

hello = "Hello World"
```

If I use `irb -r main.rb`, I get,

```
1.8.7 :001 > puts hello
NameError: undefined local variable or method `hello' for #<Object:0x7fb1486f4298>
        from (irb):1
1.8.7 :002 >
```

It only works if I have hello defined as global. So, it's actually not "python -i"'s equivalent.

So, what's the exact equivalent?

Comment: I don't think this can be done in ruby. Local vars won't become global in this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Kernel#load documentation,](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-load)

> In no circumstance will any local variables in the loaded file be
>   propagated to the loading environment.

If you don't like globals or constants, one way would be to wrap your data in a module such as: `main.rb:`

```
module Wtf
  @hello= "world"
  def self.hello; @hello end
end
```

> $ irb -r main.rb
>
> > Wtf.hello
>
> > "world"

Comment: I tried hacking with `eval File.read('main.rb'), binding`
but apparently ruby won't let you load local variables in any circumstance just like Kernel#load docs say. 
Also see [matz's (Mr. Matsumoto, creator of ruby) response at the end of this post](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/155673)

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out there is actually an evil hackish way of doing this:

```
ruby -rpry <(echo "$(cat main.rb)\nbinding.pry")
```

(requires [`pry`](https://github.com/pry/pry/) gem)

#### Explanation:

The `<(`...`)` is a Bash [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) that effectively makes a pipe containing the result of evaluating the expression in parentheses that Ruby can then evaluate.

The `echo "$(cat main.rb)\nbinding.pry"` outputs the contents of a file, in this case named `main.rb`, and adds on a newline and the Ruby code `binding.pry`, which, when combined with `require`ing `pry` with `-rpry` enables Pry's [runtime invocation](https://github.com/pry/pry/#runtime-invocation) that exposes the entire program's state to the interactive debugger.

#### Example:

(Using your `main.rb` from above)

```
$ ruby -rpry <(echo "$(cat main.rb)\nbinding.pry")

From: /proc/self/fd/11 @ line 4 :


[1] pry(main)> puts hello
Hello World
=> nil
[2] pry(main)>
```

#### Caveats:

If the logic in your program relies on accessing any variables like `_file_` or command-line arguments that are specific to running a file the correct way, it won't work. That being said, `Dir.pwd` and `require`ing seem to work normally, as long as you are executing the command from the same directory as the file.